# GetModuleFileName for window in focus JNA Windows OS

Tags: java, windows, jna

I have created this method that should return the full path and file name so that I can uniquely identify a program. However, it only returns `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe` or an empty string instead of the path for the particular program in focus. What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
private void getFocusWindow() {
    HWND focusedWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();

    char[] nameName = new char[512];
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowModuleFileName(focusedWindow, nameName, 512);

    System.out.println(nameName);
}
```

Using psapi:

**Solution:**

Provides full path and module file name, only exception is in eclipse when it prints out '�'. See @technomage's answer for more detail about GetModuleFileNameEx method.

```
private void getFocusWindow() {
    PsApi psapi = (PsApi) Native.loadLibrary("psapi", PsApi.class);

        HWND focusedWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
        byte[] name = new byte[1024];

        IntByReference pid = new IntByReference();
        User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(focusedWindow, pid);

        HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010, false, pid.getValue());
        psapi.GetModuleFileNameExA(process, null, name, 1024);
        String nameString= Native.toString(name);

        System.out.println(nameString);
}
```

psapi class:

```
public interface PsApi extends StdCallLibrary {

    int GetModuleFileNameExA(HANDLE process, HANDLE module ,
        byte[] name, int i);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get process name from process thread id in Windows OS using JNA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692460/get-process-name-from-process-thread-id-in-windows-os-using-jna)

Comment: `new Pointer(1)` and `Pointer zero` are highly suspect.  If you want to pass an integer argument, declare an integer argument in your method signature.  If you want to pass a NULL argument, pass `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetWindowModuleFileName and GetModuleFileName work only with the current process (i.e. you'll only get useful information for the current process's windows) in Windows NT 4 and later.

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469

The article recommends using the PSAPI function [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

**EDIT**

You'll need to [convert the Window handle to a module handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is probably shorter than converting window handle to PID to module handle).  Keep in mind that the window handle is just an address (so you'll need the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag).